I am running Traefik in a lxc container, Traefik keeps craching in very start complaining that there is a missing field in tls in dynamic config file
Traefik keeps crashing to start with this error message:
{"level":"error","providerName":"file","error":"/etc/traefik/config.d/config.yaml: field not found, node: tls","time":"2024-11-02T12:45:31Z","message":"Error while building configuration (for the first time)"}

Traefik.yaml content:
global:
  checkNewVersion: true

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

# enable ping so the `traefik healthcheck` works
ping: {}

providers:
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/config.d   #(prefered method to specify directory will contain many files)
    watch: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: https
          scheme: https

  https:
    address: ":443"
    http:
      tls:
        certResolver: letsEncrypt

  traefik:
    address: ":8080"

certificatesResolvers:
  letsEncrypt:
    acme:
      email: ******@*******.net   
      storage: /etc/traefik/ssl/acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"

log:
  filePath: /etc/traefik/logs/traefik.log
  format: json
  level: WARN      # more helpful

accessLog:
  filePath: /etc/traefik/logs/traefik-access.log
  format: json
  filters:
    statusCodes:
      - "200"
      - "400-599"
    retryAttempts: true
    minDuration: "10ms"
  bufferingSize: 0
  fields:
    headers:
      defaultMode: drop
      names:
        User-Agent: keep

Dynamic configiratiuons files 'config.yaml'
http:
  routers:
    traefik:
      entryPoints:
        - http
      rule: "HOST(`traefik.example.net`)"
      middlewares:
        - https-redirectscheme
        - default-headers
      service: api@internal

    traefik-secured:
      entryPoints:
        - https
      rule: "HOST(`traefik.example.net`)"
      middlewares:
        - traefik-auth
      tls:
        certResolver: letsEncrypt
        domains:
          - main: "example.net"
          - sans: 
            - "*.example.net"
      service: api@internal

    # define a connection between requests and services
    proxmox:
      entryPoints:
        - "https"
      rule: "Host(`pve.example.net`)"
      middlewares:
        - default-headers
        - https-redirectscheme
        - cors
      service: proxmox
      tls: {}

  services:
    # define how to reach an existing service
    proxmox:
      loadBalancer:
        passHostHeader: true
        servers:
          - url: "https://192.168.2.250:8006"

  middlewares:

    traefik-auth:
      basicAuth:
        users:
          - "ahmednah:$$apr1$$********$$Bq9JcuQLIetqGj/9PWUm40"

    https-redirectscheme:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: true

    default-headers:
      headers:
        frameDeny: true
        browserXssFilter: true
        contentTypeNosniff: true
        forceSTSHeader: true
        stsIncludeSubdomains: true
        stsPreload: true
        stsSeconds: 15552000
        customFrameOptionsValue: SAMEORIGIN
        customRequestHeaders:
          X-Forwarded-Proto: https

    secured:
      chain:
        middlewares:
          - default-whitelist
          - default-headers

  tls:
    stores:
      default:
        defaultGeneratedCert:
          resolver: letsEncrypt
          domain:
            main: example.net
            sans:
              - "*.example.net"

    options:
      default:
        maxVersion: VersionTLS13
        cipherSuites:
          - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
          - TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
          - TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
          - TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
      maxtls12:
        maxVersion: VersionTLS12

I gave up, I do not know what am I missing here?
